# Rechability of different interfaces without having a route in a seperate routing table

Tags: linux, routing, linux-networking, kernel, policy-routing

We're currently trying to route all packets from our guest vlan's (eth1.251) subnet trough a wireguard tunnel into the internet. To accomplish this we're using policy based routing with a rule to use the routing table 10 when the traffic is comming from our guest subnet:

```
32765:  from 10.251.0.0/16 lookup 10
```

In routing table 10 we're creating a default route towards our tunnel interface:

```
default dev wg1  scope link
```

All of our clients in our guest network are able to reache the internet through the wireguard tunnel which is expected, however the client's cannot reach the gateway for the guest network `(10.251.0.1)`. TCPDump shows that the ICMP echo reply is routed back trough the `wg1` interface to our tunnel endpoint, which is obviously not intended. A quick solution for this is to add the scope link route for the `eth1.251` guest vlan interface to the routing `table 10`:

```
default dev wg1  scope link 
10.251.0.0/16 dev eth1.251  proto kernel  scope link
```

Now the client can reach the router interface and it services.

---

On this router is another interface eth1 with the subnet `192.168.0.1/16`. When we now delete our newly added `10.251.0.0/16` route in `table 10` we cannot reach the routers interface on `10.251.0.1` anymore, however we're **still able to reach** the interface `192.168.0.1` from a client on the `10.251.0.0/16` subnet. The clients (e.g `192.168.0.2`) behind the router in the `192.168.0.0/16` subnet aren't rechable from `10.251.0.0/16`.

**Main Question**: Why can we reach the `192.168.0.1` interface ip on our router without an explicit routing table entry, but not the `10.251.0.1` interface ip from our clients in the guest `10.251.0.0/16` subnet?

Here's an overview of the network structure. I think this helps to unterstand our setup.

[image: Router interfaces overview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no general explanation, it's just the matter of following what happens in the routing settings.

10.251.0.1, is both a local router address and part of 10.251.0.0/16.

When receiving a packet to a *local* address, the router matches the *local* table using the very first `ip rule` with lowest preference: 0, before the rule for table 10, and matches. Remember that routing tables match on *destinations*, while usually the custom rules are configured to match on *sources*.

When the router replies, this time the local table doesn't match: 10.251.0.2 is not a local *destination*. Next rule is checked and matches `from 10.251.0.0/16`, looks up table 10 and packet goes through *wg1*.

For 192.168.0.1, receiving the packet is exactly like before with the *local* table. Now the answer doesn't match the additional rule, and the main routing table applies: it works as usual: a Linux system will answer from any of its IPs.

Again, for 192.168.0.2: it's not a *local* IP, so doesn't match the *local* table, but the query does match the added rule: packets are lost through *wg1*.

So copying a part of the main routing table to the extra table to avoid side effects helps.

Many of this can be tested with `ip route get` and the correct syntax, as long as there are no marks involved:

Without the additional entry in table 10:

```
# ip route get from 10.251.0.2 iif eth1.251 10.251.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid cross-device link
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1/251.rp_filter=2 #relax reverse path filtering
# ip route get from 10.251.0.2 iif eth1.251 10.251.0.1
local 10.251.0.1 from 10.251.0.2 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif eth1.251 

# ip route get from 10.251.0.2 iif eth1.251 192.168.0.1
local 192.168.0.1 from 10.251.0.2 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif eth1.251 
# ip route get from 10.251.0.2 iif eth1.251 192.168.0.2
192.168.0.2 from 10.251.0.2 dev wg1 table 10 
    cache iif eth1.251
```

reply route:

```
# ip route get from 10.251.0.1 10.251.0.2
10.251.0.2 from 10.251.0.1 dev wg1 table 10 uid 0 
    cache 
# ip route get from 192.168.0.1 10.251.0.2
10.251.0.2 from 192.168.0.1 dev eth1.251 uid 0 
    cache
```

When adding the entry in table 10:

```
# ip route get from 10.251.0.2 iif eth1.251 10.251.0.1 #even with strict reverse path filtering, since the reverse route is correct
local 10.251.0.1 from 10.251.0.2 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif eth1.251 
# ip route get from 10.251.0.1 10.251.0.2
10.251.0.2 from 10.251.0.1 dev eth1.251 table 10 uid 0 
    cache
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes absolutely sense. I just figured out instead of adding the other interface rules to the routing table 10 you can add the source interface to the ip rule from "10.251.0.0/16". This works perfectly fine and feels less hacky then adding all rules to the routing table 10.